# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unformatted' of undefined

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a GatsbyJS project where I am using `StaticQuery` to query a JSON file. I may be querying my data incorrectly but, with other react projects I haven't had this issue. I assumed the structure would be the same. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

**Error:**

[image]

**Data structure in console/inspect:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allDataJson {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              authorship_date {
                unformatted
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <header>
        {console.log(data)}
        {console.log(data.authorship_date.unformatted)}
        <p>{data.authorship_date.unformatted} test</p>
      </header>
    )}
  />
)
```

Comment: Event `{console.log(data.id)}` comes back undefined. Do I have to break into the array somehow?

Comment: as you can see in the `console.log`, `data` doesn't have a `authorship_date` property, you should try `data.allDataJson.edges[0].node.authorship_date.unformatted`

Comment: Why does the string have to be so long? Just curious if it can be shorter

Comment: No way around it, but you can make it slightly shorter with alias & the new syntax though. I post an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the console.log, data doesn't have a `authorship_date` property, you should try `data.allDataJson.edges[0].node.authorship_date.unformatted`

To make accessing a (tiny) bit less painful, you can modify the query a bit, using alias & the new shortcut (only available in gatsby ^2.2 I think). For example:

```
  query {
    json: allDataJson {
      nodes {
        id
        authorship_date {
          unformatted
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This'll cut down from

```
data.allDataJson.edges[0].node.authorship_date
```

to

```
data.json.nodes[0].authorship_date
```

And of course it's always a good idea to assign your node to a variable first so you don't have to write the whole thing every time.